# Pygame Missile Coll

Tags: python, pygame

So basically lead_x and lead_y are coordinates of a thing, and so are MineX and MineY.

```
if lead_x > XMine and lead_x < XMine + MineThickness:
    if lead_x + block_size > XMine and lead_x + block_size < XMine + MineThickness:
        if lead_y > YMine and lead_y < YMine + MineThickness:
            gameOver = True
```

Basically I wanted to create a heat-seeking missile kind of thing. The above piece of code is supposed to handle collision.

However, the collision is really glitchy. Sometimes it catches it and sometimes it doesn't.

Here's the piece of code above that, used to make the object act as a seeking missile:

```
gameDisplay.blit(mine, (XMine, YMine))
if lead_x > XMine:
       XMine += 5
if lead_x < XMine:
       XMine -= 5
if lead_y > YMine:
      YMine += 5
if lead_y < YMine:
       YMine -= 5
```

(Block_size represents the size of the missile's target, and MineThickness is the size of the missile sprite. Also, this was all made in pygame.)

Also, I know the seeking code is a but stupid but I just didn't want to get too complicated with it. If you have any suggestions I'll be glad to incorporate them :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pygame offers a lot of functionality to accomplish what you're trying to do manually. If you create your game objects using [Sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) you can just [Sprite.colliderect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to handle collision of two rectangular sprites.

If you want to do it manually you can use the [Axis-Aligned Bounding Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection) method:

```
 if (lead_x < XMine + MineThickness && lead_x + block_size > XMine):
    // x-axis constraints are met

    if (lead_y < YMine + MineThickness && block_size + lead_y > YMine):
        // y-axis constraints are met

        gameOver = True
```

This answer assumes that both of your sprites are square.